# Creating a source distribution of an Android project with ant

Tags: java, android, ant

I'm building an Android application and would like to automate the packaging of the source code (either into tarballs or zip files). Now, obviously, I could do this with a shell script that zips up everything that is relevant and ignores the Mercurial directory at the top of the source tree, but that seems kludgy.

I'm wondering if there is a "proper" way to do this with ant, in much the same way that GNU autotools would let me type "make dist" in the top level of a C project, and give me a file such as hello-0.0.1.tar.gz, containing only the source.

I'm not using Eclipse, just hand-editing files with vi and running ant manually.

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).